# Creating Multiple Tables in DB Using Same Model in ASP.NET Core Razor App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, dbset

I'm trying to make a Web App using ASP.NET Core Razor App.

While doing this, I have a trouble with creating some new tables.

Here is my `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using MyWebApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyWebApp.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        //Users
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; } //already created table

        //Freeboard
        public DbSet<Article> FreeboardArticle{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> FreeboardComment{ get; set; }

        //QuestionBoard
        public DbSet<Article> QuestionBoardArticle { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> QuestionBoardComment { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

After passing `add-migration` and `update-database` commands,

I expected that 4 tables (`FreeboardArticle`, `FreeboardComment`, `QuestionBoardArticle`, `QuestionBoardComment`) are newly created,

but actually 2 tables (`FreeboardArticle`, `FreeboardComment`) are newly created in my db.

I think why this happens is because I tried to create multiple tables using same model, but I want to do this.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

++ My model files are here.

`Article.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyWebApp.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Hit { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }


        public Article()
        {
            Hit = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

`Comment.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyWebApp.Models
{
    public class Comment
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsReply { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }


        public Comment()
        {
            IsReply = false;
            IsDeleted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

`ApplicationUser.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyWebApp.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your models look like?

Comment: @Vince I added my model files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way: have an abstract base class with all the properties, and map concrete types:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringField { get; set; }
    /* Other fields */ 
}

[Table("Table1")]
public class Table1 : BaseClass
{
}

[Table("Table2")]
public class Table2 : BaseClass
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. You could make your models inherit the common class:

**Models**

```
 public class FreeboardArticle : Article {}

 public class FreeboardComment: Comment{}

 public class QuestionBoardArticle : Article {}

 public class QuestionBoardComment : Comment{}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
 //Freeboard
 public DbSet<FreeboardArticle > FreeboardArticles{ get; set; }
 public DbSet<FreeboardComment> FreeboardComments{ get; set; }

 //QuestionBoard
 public DbSet<QuestionBoardArticle > QuestionBoardArticles { get; set; }
 public DbSet<QuestionBoardComment > QuestionBoardComments { get; set; }
```

2. Secondly you can adapt your relationships:

**Models**

```
public class Article{}

 public class Comment{}

 public class FreeboardArticle {
   public int ArticleId{get;set;}
   public virtual Article Article{get;set;}      
 }

 public class FreeboardComment {
   public int CommentId{get;set;}
   public virtual Comment Comment{get;set;}
 }

 public class QuestionBoardArticle {
   public int ArticleId{get;set;}
   public virtual Article Article{get;set;}      
 }

 public class QuestionBoardComment {
   public int CommentId{get;set;}
   public virtual Comment Comment{get;set;}
 }
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
 public DbSet<Article> Articles{ get; set; }
 public DbSet<Comment> Comments{ get; set; }

 //Freeboard
 public DbSet<FreeboardArticle > FreeboardArticles{ get; set; }
 public DbSet<FreeboardComment> FreeboardComments{ get; set; }

 //QuestionBoard
 public DbSet<QuestionBoardArticle > QuestionBoardArticles { get; set; }
 public DbSet<QuestionBoardComment > QuestionBoardComments { get; set; }
```